# Minimize a function of a variable of four variables and one parameter with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

I just started to use Mathematica. Using the following simple command to minimize a function of variables $a,b,c,d$ with parameter $n$, it takes too much time. Do you know if there is a mistake in this command syntax?

```
Minimize[{((b (b - 1)/2)*(c + d) + 
 b*a*(c + d) + (d (d - 1)/2)*(a + b) + 
 c*d*(a + b))/((a + b)*(a + b - 1)*(c + d)/
   2 + (c + d)*(c + d - 1)*(a + b)/2), a + c == n && b + d == n && n >= 1000 a >= 1 && b >= 0 && c >= 1 && d >= 0}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

Comment: Just a little curious: is there a comma missed? `n >= 1000 a >= 1` or `n >= 1000, a >= 1`?

Comment: If I guess right,`Minimize[{((b (b - 1)/2)*(c + d) + 
                    b*a*(c + d) + (d (d - 1)/2)*(a + b) + 
                    c*d*(a + b))/((a + b)*(a + b - 1)*(c + d)/     2 + (c + d)*(c + d - 1)*(a + b)/2), a + c == n, b + d == n, 
        n >= 1000 , a >= 1, b >= 0, c >= 1, d >= 0}, {a, b, c, d}]` returns what you want.

Comment: Thank you a lot @wuyudi!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assuming[n >= 1000, 
 Minimize[{((b (b - 1)/2)*(c + d) + 
       b*a*(c + d) + (d (d - 1)/2)*(a + b) + 
       c*d*(a + b))/((a + b)*(a + b - 1)*(c + d)/
         2 + (c + d)*(c + d - 1)*(a + b)/2), 
    a + c == n && b + d == n && n >= 1000 && a >= 1 && b >= 0 && 
     c >= 1 && d >= 0}, {a, b, c, d}] // Simplify]

(*{n/(2 (-1 + n)), {a -> 1, b -> n, c -> -1 + n, d -> 0}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you yarchik!